# swi-prolog won't answer query

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a query that will make sure an element is present in a list of lists, I tried this implementation:

```
membernested(E,[H|T]):-member(E,H).
membernested(E,[H|T]):-membernested(E,[T]).
```

but Prolog won't answer the query, any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you second clause to:

```
membernested(E,[H|T]) :- membernested(E,T).
```

The tail of the list `[H|T]` is `T`, not `[T]`. There's no need to enclose it in another list.